# Electron / Nw.js slow startup time (2 minutes!) on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, nw.js

Downloading the latest version of Electron (1.4.5) for Windows, I experience an unacceptable startup time (around two minutes). I've tried both the 32 and the 64bit versions. I'm trying to run the default demo app, untouched.

This happens on a specific computer, an HP Elite x2. The computer is brand new and quite performant.

System specs:
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1607)
CPU: Intel Core m5-6y54 CPU @ 1.10GHz
RAM: 8 GB

I don't think it's an hardware issue. On a much less performant Windows system it works all right. I've also tried running NW.js and it has the same problem. Visual Studio Code (built on Electron) won't start. It seems there's something wrong (possibly software of configuration-wise) with the whole node/javascript environment but I don't know where to look for a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to Windows automatic proxy detection, which causes a 21 second network timeout delay for all remote requests.

1. Hit the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, search for "Internet Options," and hit <kbd>return</kbd>. Alternatively, in Google Chrome, click the <kbd>...</kbd> in the upper right corner, select Settings, then click the "Change proxy settings..." button.
2. Under the "Connections" tab, click "LAN settings".
3. Uncheck "Automatically detect settings"
4. Click OK, OK, and reboot.

[image: Windows 10 Internet Settings dialog]